# Extension method for Sorting a generic iCollection(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, properties, icollection

I'm trying to extend a generic collection to be sortable by my own criteria.

This is how I've been doing it using Linq:

```
Dim sortedList = ViewCollection.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.ViewName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Trim.All(AddressOf Char.IsLetter)).ThenByDescending(Function(x) x.ViewName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Trim.Any(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)).ThenBy(Function(x) x.ViewName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Trim).ToList()
```

So, this is the sorting method extension I'm working on:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Public Function SortCollection(Of T)(ByVal Collection As ICollection(Of T), ByVal PropertyName As String) As ICollection(Of T)

            For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In Collection.GetType().GetProperties()
                If p.Name = PropertyName Then
                    result = Collection.ToList() ' I need to replace this with the sorting criteria posted above
                End If
            Next

            Return result
        End Function
```

I can't seem find a way on how to pass what property from this generic object I want to use as for alphabetic sorting criteria.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain a [PropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx) and use this to sort the collection.

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function Sort(Of T)(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal propertyName As String, direction As ListSortDirection) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim descriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(T)).Find(propertyName, True)
    If (direction = ListSortDirection.Descending) Then
        Return (From item As T In collection Select item Order By descriptor.GetValue(item) Descending)
    Else
        Return (From item As T In collection Select item Order By descriptor.GetValue(item) Ascending)
    End If
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, {"xxxxx", "xxx", "x", "xxxx", "xx"}.Sort("Length", ListSortDirection.Ascending)))
```

Output:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
```

Comment: Thanks very much mate, I will give it a good try but it seems pretty close to what I am looking for. I just need to cater for nested properties as well like "View.Name" so I will investigate how to nest expressions. But this is pretty close. Cheers